# 2 rows, first on top and second on bottom of parent

Tags: html, css

I have a absolute container (must remain absolute), with fixed height and i need to place 2 li inside, one on top and second at the bottom. Both li's have variable height and i must not use absolute position for the bottom one (will break something in the menu).

The structure is

```
<div id="container">
<div id="top">
    top variable height
</div>
<div id="bottom">bottom variable height</div>
```

You can see olso a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Adyyda/3bsa7hco/)

Any idea how to do it? Thanks

Comment: So, you want `#bottom` to occupy any remaining width inside of `#container` after the height of `#top` has been taken into account?

Comment: I forgot to mention that any solution must work in IE8 without additional jquery like css pie or others.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using Flex property.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9vq8nkpc/

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="top">
        top variable height
    </div>
    <div id="bottom">bottom variable heighbottom variable heightbottom variable heightbottom variable heightbottom variable heightbottom variable heightbottom variable heightbottom variable heightbottom variable heightbottom variable heightbottom variable heightbottom variable heightbottom variable heightbottom variable heightbottom variable heightbottom variable heightbottom variable heightbottom variable heightbottom variable heightt</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content:space-between;
}
#top, #bottom {
    border: 2px solid red;
    background: #ccc;
    width:80%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but i need one that works in ie8 as well - sorry that i forgot to mention this- http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: ahh, well that is a thing. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 2):

If it's possible to change HTML, you can use display: table for container and display: table-cell for additional container, then you can vertically align the content. To make first li stay at top, there can be used absolute positioning.

```css
#container {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 200px;
    width: 90%;
    position: absolute;
    display: table;
}
#top, #bottom {
    border: 2px solid red;
    background: #ccc;
    width:80%;
    display: inline-block;
}

#top{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.table-cell{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="table-cell">
            <div id="top">top variable height</div>
            <div id="bottom">bottom variable height</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3bsa7hco/1/

Comment: Unfortunately i can not change the structure because thisi is part of a complex vertical megamenu for desktop and responsive devices. Thanks anyway for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote that `bottom` cannot have absolute positioning, but you didn't say the same about `top`.

In that case, you can use these styles:

```
#top {
  position: absolute;            //so top won't affect bottom's placement
}

#bottom {
  position: relative;            //relative to container
  top: 100%;                     //height of container ...
  transform: translateY(-100%);  //... minus height of bottom element
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ozzjwpro/)

Comment: This looks good except ie8 which does not support it http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d - sorry, i have forgot to mention that the fix must work native in ie8 since i have done a lot of ie8 fixes in the whole website.

Comment: Yeah, that would also be a problem with a flex solution.  Your best bet may be @Julia 's table solution.

Comment: Unfortunately i can not change the structure because will mess up the megamenu in which i am using this code.